# Array length with objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following array with objects:

My test data:

> const testData = [{ 'data':{   'points':[{
>       'lib':0.01,
>       'zero':2.00   }] } }]

My Class:

```
class DataClass{


  constructor(lib, zero){
     this.lib = lib; 
     this.zero = zero;
  }

Here my function:

 createData(backendData) {
      const test = backendData[0]['data'].points
       const chartData = test.map((rf) => {
      return new DataClass(
        rf.lib,
        rf.zero)
    })
      return chartData;
}
}

let test = new DataClass();
let testA = test.createData(testData)
console.log(testA.length) ---> Here I am getting error..
```

Solution:

I forgot the return the value. In my case the chartData

Comment: `testData.length`?

Comment: Is that Java code?

Comment: *"Here I am getting error.."* You are not saying which error you get but the problem with your code is that `createData` doesn't return a value.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

actually the only thing that is weird on your code is the `TESTOBJECT` keyword before every `object` inside the `array`.

here you have a working example, also, check that I had to remove the `TESTOBJECT` word or it won't work.

```js
let testData = [{
  lib: 0.02,
  timo: 0.0794,
  zeroRateAnnualized: 0.03
}, {
  lib: 0.06,
  timo: 0.0894,
  zeroRateAnnualized: 0.06
}, {
  lib: 0.09,
  timo: 0.0994,
  zeroRateAnnualized: 0.08
}, {
  lib: 0.29,
  timo: 0.1994,
  zeroRateAnnualized: 0.18
}];

console.log(testData.length);
```

Comment: @NoahTony then you are not writing the correct `Array`. we need an example of how the data is on your side to try to replicate the issue/problem.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the Array don't matter when calculating the length, just the number of elements.

So,

```
const myArrayOfStrings = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

const myArrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3 , 4]
```

and

```
const myArrayOfObjects = [{lib: 0.02, timo: 0.0794, zeroRateAnnualized: 0.03}, 
                          {lib: 0.06, timo: 0.0894, zeroRateAnnualized: 0.06}, 
                          {lib: 0.09, timo: 0.0994, zeroRateAnnualized: 0.08}, 
                          {lib: 0.29, timo: 0.1994, zeroRateAnnualized: 0.18}];
```

all have a length of 4

To find the length of the array use `myArrayOfObjects.length`

The array you are trying to get the length of cannot exist:
[image]

Comment: Please see my question again

Comment: @Noah Tony You cannot get the length of that array because it is not a valid array as Prince Hernandez pointed out.

Comment: @JonathanRys you saw the same as I did, 
`TESTOBJECT {.....}` is not a valid entry for an array.